# Callback parameter type mismatch causing incorrect value

Tags: android, c++, callback, parameter-passing

I'm doing some callback in c++.
For example, the function is defined as:

```
void myFunction1(int arg1, float arg2) {
    // ...
}
```

The callback is defined as:

```
typedef void (*callback_if_t )( const int64, const float );
callback_if_t pFunc = (callback_if_t)& myFunction1;

( *( callback_if_t ) pFunc )( 1, 0.5 );
```

As you see, the callback first parameter type is different with the one it pointed to.

On Windows OS, this is alright, the parameters are passed into myFunction1 correctly.

But on android, I got incorrect values for both two parameters in myFunction1.
Obviously it's caused by the mismatched type of first parameter, the stack has being corrupted.

To resolve this problem, the most direct way is correcting the type, but I need int64 param to pass some pointer to compatible with 64bit version, otherwise, I'll have to add millions of callback types T^T.

I'm not quite clear about the c++ mechanism, or the difference between windows and android.
Can anyone explain this to me, any chance to find a cheap way to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the purpose of the callback? Why don't you just call the function directly?

Comment: the code is just a demo, the callback assignment and invoke are at different place, I use it for encapsulation purpose.

Comment: Put the `&myFunction1` in parentheses